# Client Side Cache Protobuf Vector Tiles - LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet, protocol-buffers, browser-cache, vector-tiles

I'm running a small flask app to serve tiles to a LeafletJS map. The tiles are served as protobufs and loaded with the below.

```
var loadLineAreas = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(window.origin + "/tiles/loadline/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf", vectorTileOption)

MapName.addLayer(loadLineAreas)
```

This works and the tiles a rendered correctly.

Other layers from third partys include WMS tiles and L.tileLayer tiles which automatically cache with LeafletJS, but my tiles from the above do not.

Any suggestions on how to client side cache `L.vectorGrid.protobuf` ?

Comment: [Service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks you so much for the direction into the world of service workers (my clients will be on ships so this has been a game changer!).